# Weka Apriori Algorithm convert dataset

Tags: weka, data-mining, apriori

How can I use this dataset with Weka for Apriori Algorithm ?

```
'A, C, D',
'B, C, E',
'A, B, C, E',
'B, E'
```

Comment: If you remove the comma and quotation marks, you can use it with ELKI Apriori IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert it in `.arff` format.

The format of an `.arff` file is simple, is composed by three fields:

```
@relation

@attribute

@data
```

In case like this, where you have only a single field ("letters" in your case) you should list all the possible attribute (A,B,C,..) in the attribute field, and then format it (in data field) using boolean values describing presence/absence of the specific attribute in each line.

Example:

```
@relation <file_name>

@attribute 'A' { t}
@attribute 'B' { t}
@attribute 'C' { t}
@attribute 'D' { t}
@attribute 'E' { t}

@data
t, ?, t, t, ?
?, t, t, ?, t
t, t, t, ?, t
?, t, ?, ?, t
```

As an other example, look at the example of "supermarket.arff" in Weka data folder.